# VBA: Why is my INSERT code not working?

Tags: vba, insert

I had this working a few weeks ago but now I'm not sure what I did that made it not work anymore. I don't even get an error message to figure out what could be wrong. When I click the button I made to insert a row into the table, nothing happens. The form gets cleared and the table gets requeried, but the INSERT part of the code doesn't do anything.

```
Public Sub Command125_Click()
    'Add row for downtime

    Dim dbsCurrent As Database
    Set dbsCurrent = CurrentDb

    dbsCurrent.Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_Downtime " _
    & "(job, suffix, production_date, reason, downtime_minutes, comment, shift) VALUES " _
    & "('" & Me.Text116 & "','" & Me.Text118 & "','" & Me.Text126 & "','" & Me.Text121 & "','" & Me.Text123 & "','" & Me.Text128 & "','" & Me.Text144 & "');"

   Call ClearControl(Me.Text116)
   Call ClearControl(Me.Text118)
   Call ClearControl(Me.Text126)
   Call ClearControl(Me.Text121)
   Call ClearControl(Me.Text123)
   Call ClearControl(Me.Text128)
   Call ClearControl(Me.Text144)

   Me.subrpt_DowntimeTable.Requery

End Sub
```

---

**The code I'm trying based on @Hambone's answer:**

```
Public Sub Command125_Click()

Dim dbsCurrent As Database
Set dbsCurrent = CurrentDb

Dim query As QueryDef
    Dim sql As String

    For Each query In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
      If query.Name = "InsertDowntime" Then
        Exit For
      End If
    Next query

    If query Is Nothing Then
      sql = "parameters " & _
        "P1 text, P2 text, P3 Date, P4 Text, P5 Number, P6 Text, P7 Text;" & _
        "insert into [tbl_Downtime] " & _
        "(job, suffix, production_date, reason, downtime_minutes, comment, shift) " & _
        " VALUES ([P1], [P2], [P3], [P4], [P5], [P6], [P7])"

      Set query = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("InsertDowntime", sql)
    End If

    query.Parameters("P1").Value = "test1"
    query.Parameters("P2").Value = "test2"
    query.Parameters("P3").Value = Now()
    query.Parameters("P4").Value = "test3"
    query.Parameters("P5").Value = 15
    query.Parameters("P6").Value = "Miles O'Brien is a darn good transporter chief"
    query.Parameters("P7").Value = "test6"

    query.Execute

    MsgBox query.Parameters("P1").Value & query.Parameters("P2").Value & query.Parameters("P3").Value & query.Parameters("P4").Value & query.Parameters("P5").Value & query.Parameters("P6").Value & query.Parameters("P7").Value

    Me.subrpt_DowntimeTable.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @MarcB This is a form to be used only within the company's network. I'm not worried about SQL injection.

Comment: good luck with that attitude when someone files the comment `Miles O'Brien is a darn good transporter chief`. just because the payload isn't "malicious" doesn't mean you DON'T have a problem.

Comment: Honestly, "Only available within the company's network", is not a very good excuse. It is very simple to rewrite this using parametrized queries. Along with securing your statements, it has the added benefit of making it easier to read and diagnose problems.

Comment: No, seriously, it's not a problem. We have tons of forms that users here use to fill in info. We don't have these problems. Can we focus on what I'm asking now? Thanks.

Comment: Well, the thing is, what we are telling you would help you solve this problem almost instantly. The likeliest issue you are having here is that a value being passed into your statement is not correct (either it contains a single quote, or some other invalid value). Try storing the query string into a variable and printing it out to see what is being executed. The only thing that "We have tons of forms that users here use..." means to me, is that it is being done wrong everywhere in your company. It may work in most cases, but if/when it breaks, it is a nightmare to track down and fix.

Comment: @gmiley it's more of making the barest bones of Access forms and training people to use them without screwing things up. But for the comment field, yes, someone could *potentially* write useless or goofy things in there. But if you were to ask me if I ever see that happening, it's a hard no. No one who will use this form will be goofing off and putting useless info in there because it's going to be sent to their supervisors.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat You could run into problems if someone puts anything containing a single quote, so if Sharron over in accounting types in: `Jim's Paycheck was delivered Friday.`, your code will not work. And that is just one small, but frequently encountered example of potential unintentional problems.

Comment: @gmiley I see...I guess I was interpreting only malicious code to be inserted, but if single quotes are going to cause a problem, then I need to fix it. How would I do this for the comment field? I'll make everything else a combo box where the user will pick from a list.

Comment: That is what we were saying earlier. You would want to use a parametrized query, I will add an answer directing you to an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MarkB and gmiley are absolutely right about using parameters.  It's a little more code up front and countless hours saved later.  And, it's a good practice to get into.

That said, for a native Access query (not a ADO Database query), it's not the most straight-forward process in the world.  The normal ADO stuff, in my opinion, starts to make sense after you do it a time or two, but for an Access query, I still have to go back and plagiarize old examples to get it to work.

In your case, I think something like this will do the trick:

```
  Dim query As QueryDef
  Dim sql As String

  For Each query In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
    If query.Name = "InsertDowntime" Then
      Exit For
    End If
  Next query

  If query Is Nothing Then
    sql = "parameters " & _
      "P1 text, P2 text, P3 Date, P4 Text, P5 Number, P6 Text, P7 Text;" & _
      "insert into [tbl_Downtime] " & _
      "(job, suffix, production_date, reason, downtime_minutes, comment, shift) " & _
      " VALUES ([P1], [P2], [P3], [P4], [P5], [P6], [P7])"

    Set query = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("InsertDowntime", sql)
  End If

  query.Parameters("P1").Value = "test1"
  query.Parameters("P2").Value = "test2"
  query.Parameters("P3").Value = Now()
  query.Parameters("P4").Value = "test3"
  query.Parameters("P5").Value = 15
  query.Parameters("P6").Value = "Miles O'Brien is a darn good transporter chief"
  query.Parameters("P7").Value = "test6"

  query.Execute
```

You were pulling your data from text-boxes.  I used hard-coded values to demonstrate that this also manages data-typing if your values are not all text.  No need to 'quote' text or #hash# dates.  You can obviously changes these back to `Me.TextBox123` and alter the data types to match your actual fields in `tbl_Downtime`.

-- edit 12/3/15 --

The entire section of code from `For Each query In CurrentDb.QueryDefs` all the way prior to `query.Parameters` could *theoretically* be omitted if you already had a query with this query text in it (as in you went into Access, created a query, went from Design view to SQL view and typed this in and named it `InsertDowntime`):

```
parameters
P1 text, P2 text, P3 Date, P4 Text, P5 Number, P6 Text, P7 Text;
insert into [tbl_Downtime]
(job, suffix, production_date, reason, downtime_minutes, comment, shift)
VALUES ([P1], [P2], [P3], [P4], [P5], [P6], [P7])
```

Because you don't, I just created that through code.  If you tried to create it again, Access would puke because `InsertDowntime` already exists.

Either way, once it exists, the way you can manage it is by saying

```
Dim query As QueryDef
Set query = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("InsertDowntime")
```

And then everything else *should* be as I have it.

Personally, I would go option 2 -- create the query in Access and keep it as a persistent object and access it the way I just listed above.  I suppose I could have said that, but yours was a VBA-ish question, and I kept it VBA -- plus, I thought the ability to create a query dynamically is sort of cool.

Comment: That is checking to see if the query was already created, and if so, use it instead of creating a new one.  There is overhead (however minimal) associated with creating a queryDef, so rather than creating it over and over we can create it once and leverage it for multiple inserts.  Alternatively, you could create this query through the designer and simply use it `query = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("InsertDowntime")`, but that's up to you.  I'm curious if you try this and how it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working :( I've edited my question to show the code I'm using.

Comment: Ah, I found something. What do you make of this: when I add an `Else` statement to the end of the `If query...`, it results in the `Else` statement returning true. In simpler terms, I put `Else: MsgBox "Query is something"` and now when I click the button that's exactly what my form is displaying. Afterwards it also displays the parameters but that's irrelevant.

Comment: Actually, I don't even understand the QueryDef and "InsertDowntime" parts at all. I feel like the problem might be because something should be named "InsertDowntime" on my form but there isn't. Is that why?

Comment: Rather than fit it into a comment, I added an "extended comment" into my answer.  Can I ask when you step through the code, where does it error, and what's the error message?  Or does it run successfully and just not do anything?  Out of curiosity, I created a database with a table the way I think you have it, and this did work for me.  Can you add an image of your table, so I can see the fields and definitions?  That may lend a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: [Here is a screenshot of my table in design view](http://postimg.org/image/e3vce56zb/).

Comment: Yup, the problem was the ID field. Once I forced Access to show me what was causing the error, it said it was coming from the tbl_Downtime.ID that I needed to enter a value. It was because I switched it to Number sometime ago while tinkering around with this. I changed it back to autonumber and it works now!

Comment: Couple of questions though: 1) So I won't have to worry about any punctuation that the users could enter into the comment field? 2) What if I switched one of the textboxes to a combobox? Will I need to change anything 3) Validation in general - I need to ensure that users only input certain information. Someone at work suggested that I fill out each textbox based on a preceding textbox using a query. So if they enter in the Production Date of this past Monday, that will narrow down what jobs they can enter. Then if they select a certain job, they can only select certain reasons...etc..

Comment: Is validation possible in VB for Access?

Comment: With parameters, assuming the datatype matches, you don't have to worry about anything.  It will handle carriage returns, quotes, tabs, whatever.  Same thing with dates, as long as it's a real date.  I think it's reasonably forgiving with datatypes also, but I'd be dogmatic about that if I were you.  If you switch to a combobox, that should be no issue, provided you pick the right property from it.  I'm guessing it would be ComboBox.Text or perhaps ComboBox.SelectedItem

Comment: Alrighty, I'll give it a shot. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Regarding validation, yes it's definitely possible.  That said, I have to admit I'm a C# and Perl guy and only do VBA in passing -- it's nearly impossible to not know VBA in the computing industry, and it is awful handy.  I have definitely seen Access DBs that do validation, though, so I know it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would not build the SQL-Statement in the Execute-Method.
Create a variable and build the string first. So you can debug the actual value and test it seperately.

You can also try the Option `dbFailOnError` for the Execute-Method.

```
Dim stmt as String
stmt = "INSERT INTO....."
dbsCurrent.Execute stmt, dbFailOnError
```

Test the INSERT Statement with different inputs. It is not important what a normal user will enter in a form but what he is allowed to do by the application. If the input is not checked and the user can enter everything he/she wants's then the query can fail, produce weird results or - as stated - allows SQL injection. The best SQL injection is the one you as a developer will never notice. So you would'n know that you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion, you would want to look into parametrized queries: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/181734

The primary reasons for this are that 1) It will ensure your code is safe from intentional or unintentional SQL injection. Since user input cannot always be controlled in free-form fields, ensuring that your query is parametrized makes it impossible to execute arbitrary code; and 2) Readability, it makes it a lot easier to read code when the values are parametrized.