# How to Split a String and Store in MS Access table

Tags: string, vba, ms-access, split

I would like to be able to split a string of text that has been entered into a textbox on a MS Access form and store the split strings as separate records under the same field.  This is the code I have so far, but I keep running into problems at every corner.  I'm fairly new to this, but have been learning quickly.  Any help is appreciated.

Here is what I'd like to accomplish:  If I enter the following text into a text box ("this is a sentence") and click submit.  I would like each other the words to be stored as individual records under a common field.  Seems simple, but it's causing quite a few headaches.

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()

    Dim SetDBConnection As ADODB.Connection
    Set SetDBConnection = CurrentProject.Connection

    Dim strInsertRecord As String

    Dim strNewPhrase As String
    Dim strStorePhrase As String

    strNewPhrase = textPhrase
    strStorePhrase = Split(NewPhrase)

    strInsertRecord = "INSERT INTO [FieldSplice] (words) VALUES (" & strStorePhrase & ")"
    SetDBConnection.Execute strInsertRecord

    textPhrase.Value = Null
End Sub
```

Comment: You should specify where you are stuck

Comment: There is no such thing as `individual records under a common field`. Either you are trying to do something that databases don't do or you are using the wrong terms to describe your problem.

Each record on a database table has a unique value for each field. You cannot store multiple values in a single field unless you do it using multiple records.

If that is what you are trying to do then you must iterate through the members of the array `strStorePhrase` and use an `INSERT` statement for each member. And strStorePhrase needs to be declared as an array: `Dim strStorePhrase() As String`

Comment: Here is one problem in your code: `strStorePhrase = Split(NewPhrase)` That's a problem because `Split()` returns an array and `strStorePhrase` is a plain `String` variable ... so can't accept an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a little unclear on why you have the ADODB connection...  is this connecting to an external database?  If so, that makes sense, but then you are missing some code to get the insert to work properly.

If this is just an internal (native) Access table, then I don't think you need any of that.  Here is a simple example of how you would take a string, split it into words (based on a space) and then insert those into your table:

```
Dim textPhrase As String
Dim words() As String
Dim i As Integer

textPhrase = "This is a test"
words = Split(textPhrase, " ")

sql = "parameters P1 text; INSERT INTO [FieldSplice] (words) VALUES ([P1])"

Set query = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("FsInsert", sql)

For i = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
  query.Parameters("P1").Value = words(i)
  query.Execute
Next i

CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete ("FsInsert")
```

One other note of interest -- you don't need to declare the insert each time.  You can set a parameter, assign values to the parameter and execute the insert command multiple times.  This is included in my example above.

Your code was trying to say:

```
insert into [table] (field) values ("value1", "value2", "value3")
```

Which you can't do.  That has to be done as three inserts, unless your database supports array inserts (Oracle, for example).

The multiple fields only works like this:

```
insert into [table] (field1, field2) values ("value1", "value2")
```

Where each value corresponds to a column in the table.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Hambone (it's very appreciated), I'm stuck with these two lines.  How do I set my parameters correctly?  I'm just a little confused as to what P1 actually is.  

sql = "parameters P1 text; INSERT INTO [FieldSplice] (words) VALUES ([P1])"

Set query = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("FsInsert", sql)

Is there anything else I can provide you that would make this easier for you to understand?  This is the first question I've ever posted on stackoverflow.

Comment: I managed to get your code to work. One thing to note, I had to change the "Set query =" statement in your code to "set qdf =".  Do you know why?

Here is the final code:

Private Sub Command8_Click()

Dim textPhrase As String
Dim words() As String
Dim i As Integer

textPhrase = phrase
words = Split(textPhrase, " ")

SQL = "parameters P1 text;INSERT INTO [FieldSplice] (words) VALUES ([P1])"

Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("FsInsert", SQL)

For i = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
  qdf.Parameters("P1").Value = words(i)
  qdf.Execute
Next i

CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete ("FsInsert")
End Sub

Comment: Thanks so much for your help by the way.  Happy holidays.

Comment: `qdf` is just the variable name...  it looks like I forgot to `Dim` my variable named "query" as a QueryDef.  My mistake.  Maybe you had query defined elsewhere as a string, which is why it didn't work but qdf didn't?  As far as P1, that's just the name of the bind variable.  You can name it anything you want.  P1 is sort of generic -- Parameter 1.  As long as the variable is consistent between the two statements, it can be anything you want.  At any rate, I'm glad you got it to work.  Thanks for the kind words, and have a great Christmas

Comment: By the way, here is a more comprehensive example of parameters in Access where multiple columns are inserted:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023850/vba-why-is-my-insert-code-not-working/34033843#34033843  Bear in mind Access parameters are very different (not as straight-forward in my opinion) than normal parameters for a RDBMS using ADO.net