# Insert new record using parameters

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm still learning, I want to insert data into table, but get (Run-time Error '3061', Too few Paramaters . Expected 38)

I've been looking about error around a weeks, I've checked the columns that I should give bracket but get nothing. I've tracked using break point, I get all value, so I don't understand why. Thank You for the advance

```
 strSQL = " INSERT Into Tbl_Mst_Lisensi(Kode_Lisensi, ID_License, Jdl_BhsIndonesia, Jdl_BhsInggris, SKK, TD, FG, SP, SG, PreTest, PostTest, KT, SE, SOP, SOPQ, Format, [Note], Current_Resources, Training, Status_Del, [Group], SKK_Ver, TD_Ver, FG_Ver, SP_Ver, SG_Ver, PreTest_Ver, PostTest_Ver,  KT_Ver, SE_Ver, SOP_Ver, SOPQ_Ver, [Date_Created], Id_Group, Id_SubGroup, [User_CDO], [User_Proposed], [User_Approved] )" & vbCrLf & _
                " VALUES ([pKode_Lisensi], [pID_License], [pJdl_BhsIndonesia], [pJdl_BhsInggris], [pSKK], [pTD], [pFG], [pSP], [pSG], [pPreTest], [pPostTest], [pKT], [pSE], [pSOP], [pSOPQ], [pFormat], [pNote], [pCurrent_Resources], [pTraining], [pStatus_Del], [pGroup], [pSKK_Ver], [pTD_Ver], [pFG_Ver], [pSP_Ver], [pSG_Ver], [pPreTest_Ver], [pPostTest_Ver],  [pKT_Ver], [pSE_Ver], [pSOP_Ver], [pSOPQ_Ver], [pDate_Created], [pId_Group], [pId_SubGroup], [pUser_CDO], [pUser_Proposed], [pUser_Approved] );"

 Set db = CurrentDb
 Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSQL)

      qdf.Parameters("pKode_Lisensi").Value = Me.txt_KodeLisensi.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pID_License").Value = Me.cmb_idLic.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pJdl_BhsIndonesia").Value = Me.txtBhsIndo.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pJdl_BhsInggris").Value = Me.txtBhsInggris.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pSKK").Value = iSKK
      qdf.Parameters("pTD").Value = iTD
      qdf.Parameters("pFG").Value = iFG
      qdf.Parameters("pSP").Value = iSP
      qdf.Parameters("pSG").Value = iSG
      qdf.Parameters("pPreTest").Value = iPre
      qdf.Parameters("pPostTest").Value = iPost
      qdf.Parameters("pKT").Value = iKT
      qdf.Parameters("pSE").Value = iSE
      qdf.Parameters("pSOP").Value = iSOP
      qdf.Parameters("pSOPQ").Value = iSOPQ
      qdf.Parameters("pFormat").Value = Me.txtFormat.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pNote").Value = Me.txtNote.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pCurrent_Resources").Value = Me.txtResources.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pTraining").Value = Me.AttcFile.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pStatus_Del").Value = i
      qdf.Parameters("pGroup").Value = del
      qdf.Parameters("pSKK_Ver").Value = Me.txtSKK.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pTD_Ver").Value = Me.txtTD.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pFG_Ver").Value = Me.txtFG.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pSP").Value = Me.txtSP.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pSG_Ver").Value = Me.txtSG.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pPreTest_Ver").Value = Me.txtPre.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pPostTest_Ver").Value = Me.txtPost.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pKT_Ver").Value = Me.txtKT.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pSE_Ver").Value = Me.txtSE.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pSOP_Ver").Value = Me.txtSOP.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pSOPQ_Ver").Value = Me.txtSOPQ.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pDate_Created").Value = Me.txt_DateTime.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pId_Group").Value = Me.Combo18.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pId_SubGroup").Value = Me.cmbSubGroup.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pUser_CDO").Value = Me.cmbCDO.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pUser_Proposed").Value = Me.txtProposed.Value
      qdf.Parameters("pUser_Approved").Value = Me.txtApproved.Value

     qdf.Execute
```

Comment: Check your parameters ordering. At least one of them is probably missing, because of the exception text - ... Too few Paramaters . Expected 38

Comment: Function you have used in code is a bit dated, but read end of that article with example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-createquerydef-method-dao Their description and your using differs. See the end of article - there is extended example.

Comment: I've checked the order  3 times, there is no missing

Comment: Thank you, I've  read your link, than I get this reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023850/vba-why-is-my-insert-code-not-working

But I still get error : "Query Must have at least one destination field"

Comment: How does your query seems now? It seems you have some mistake in some reserved keyword of it.

Comment: Every reference to `Parameters` in your code must have a match in SQL to a parameter declared in the PARAMETERS clause, like: `PARAMETERS pKode_Lisensi INTEGER, ..., pUser_Approved BIT;`

Comment: Also, the parameter order makes no difference, either in the code or the PARAMETERS clause. Order is not important in the INSERT statement, except that every value must be correctly paired with its field name. What *does* matter is that the lists are complete, and that all the names are spelled the same.

Comment: I change the code to the simple one.
using : insert to table() than values(), it's use only for my internal office.
Thank you for the advance